# Pass NULL argument with JQ --arg

Tags: json, arguments, parameter-passing, jq

My desired end state is a JSON file like this:

```
{
   "xxx": null
}
```

but the command `jq --null-input --arg tst null '.xxx=$tst'` produces:

```
{
  "xxx": "null"
}
```

and `jq --null-input --arg tst "" '.xxx=$tst'` produces:

```
{
  "xxx": ""
}
```

How can I pass a value that becomes the value `null` and not string `"null"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `--argjson`, not `--arg`.

```
$ jq --null-input --argjson tst null '.xxx=$tst'
{
  "xxx": null
}
```

`--arg` always treats the assigned value as a string, while `--argjson` treats it as a JSON value.

Answer (score 0):

Three other simple possibilities, shortest first:

```
jq -n '{xxx: .}'
```

```
echo null | jq  '{xxx: .}'
```

```
jq -n --argjson xxx null  '{$xxx}'
```